# Must spin glasses really have an exponential density of states close to the ground state?

Tags: quantum-spin, spin-models, density-of-states

I'm a complete beginner to spin glasses. I'm not even sure of the definition; I've mostly seen examples, like Sherrington-Kirkpatric with all-all pairwise normally distributed Ising interactions. However, I'm under the impression that the long-range interactions are not essential.

The typical picture I get is that frustration in systems with random interactions means there are many states of similar energy that are locally very different; you'd have to flip many spins to go between states of similar energy, which leads to "glassy" phenomena like long-lived autocorrelation functions when adding in simple dynamics at finite temperature. However, I'm confused by some common statements made about spin glasses and their density of states, and whether the density of states is exponential in system size near the ground state.

What is the density of states of a classical spin glass as a function of energy near the ground state energy? For example, are there an $O(1)$, a polynomial in the number of spins $\text{Poly}(N)$, or super-polynomial in the number of spins, like $e^{\text{Poly}(N)}$, states within an $O(1)$ energy of the ground state? I've heard it said that the number is exponential, but I wonder whether that's only for states of finite energy density in the thermodynamic limit, not states within an $O(1)$ energy of the ground state.

Similarly, one can imagine adding a transverse magnetic field, translationally invariant or disordered, to classical spin glasses to make quantum spin glasses. What does the density of states near the ground state look for such systems? In general, without fine-tuning or many-body interactions, I suspect it's hard to get an exponential density of states within an O(1) energy of the ground state in a quantum system, so I again feel skeptical that the density of states could be growing exponentially in system size close to the ground state.

---

Edit:

One thought is that the gap between the ground state(s) and the next excited state, and the degeneracy at low energies, may well be model dependent. For example, one could imagine three versions of Sherrington-Kirkpatrick, one with normally distributed interactions, another with $\pm 1$ interactions, and another with interactions distributed in $[a,b]\cup[-b, -a]$. The first type of interaction with normal variables ensures that the density of states diverges at least polynomially with system size, since there will be some very small interaction strengths for which spins can be flipped with little cost. The second, with $\pm 1$ interactions, may have degenerate ground states, but the next highest energy will have a gap of $1$ or $2$ relative to the ground state. The third is in-between and maybe the most natural - neither a gap nor gaplessness is guaranteed, at least not obviously a priori.