# How does the energy gap in the all-to-all random Ising (Sherrington-Kirkpatrick) model scale with system size?

Tags: energy, spin-models, density-of-states, disorder

Recently, I asked the question [Must spin glasses really have an exponential density of states close to the ground state?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/733328/must-spin-glasses-really-have-an-exponential-density-of-states-close-to-the-grou). Here, I give a related, more specific question, whose answer may give steps towards answering my original question.

The Sherrington-Kirkpatrick model considers a set of $N$ classical spins $\sigma_i = \pm 1$ with normally-distributed pairwise all-to-all interactions:
$$H = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{i<j} J_{ij} \sigma_i \sigma_j\text{, } J_{ij} \sim N(0,1)$$

The ground state is exactly two-fold degenerate given the Ising symmetry of the model. However, what is the energy gap $\Delta$ to the next excited state above this two-fold degenerate ground state manifold? Here, I'm mostly just concerned with the asymptotic scaling in system size $N$. For example, is the gap asymptotically constant at large system sizes, polynomially shrinking in $N$, or exponentially shrinking in $N$?

I would have thought the answer to be exponentially shrinking in $N$, but I ran some numerics and I'm consistently getting what looks to be an asymptotically nonvanishing gap, completely against my expectations! Here's data from 10000 realizations for system sizes $N$ between $4$ and $13$, predicting an asymptotic gap $\Delta_{\infty}$ from a best fit of the form $\Delta_{\infty} + c/N$ of around $.3$ as $N \to \infty$:

[image: Plot of gap against inverse system size]

Admittedly, these are for rather small sizes and there's the possibility of a typo in my code, but it's strikingly against my rough expectations.